# Custom validation message not working in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-validation

I want to display custom validation messages for max length and min length of phone number.
I have written this code to display custom validation message for max length and min length of phone number field.

```
['phone', 'string', 'max' => 12, 'min' => 8, 'message' => 'Please enter a valid Phone number.']
```

The validation is working well however custom message is not being displayed. everytime is shows this default yii2 message "Phone should contain at most 12 characters."

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

Update:
If you want to use **number validator** you can use the following:

```
['phone', 'number', 'max' => 12, 'min' => 8, 'tooBig' => 'Please enter a valid Phone number.', 'tooSmall' => 'Please enter a valid Phone number.']
```

If you want to use **string validator** you can use the following:

```
['phone', 'string', 'max' => 12, 'min' => 8, 'tooLong' => 'Please enter a valid Phone number.', 'tooShort' => 'Please enter a valid Phone number.']
```

Comment: I am getting this Exception error if i use your code  "Exception (Unknown Property) 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Setting unknown property: yii\validators\StringValidator::tooBig' "               Do i need to include any class for it

Comment: use number instead of string .. I updated the answer .. Please check and let me know whether it works for you.

Comment: @Chinmay could you edit the answer to highlight the changes? Comments can be deleted.

Comment: Just an observation, but using a number field to store telephone numbers may not be a good idea. You will lose a leading zero on saving, and it doesn't allow you to store word characters like + or () that may be in an international telephone number. I usually use a varchar field.

Comment: @JoeMiller: I agree with you, since the OP used the min and max property that's why I suggested to use the number validator instead of string.

Comment: sorry but that works for value of phone number but not for length.

Comment: @VinitSingh: See the updated answer, if you want to use string validator. you can use tooshort and toolong for it.